# Take Out the Year of Date and Convert Month in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, xml, date

I'm using

```
$this(find).text()
```

to parse XML in Javascript.

The output of the date from the text in the XML outputs as follows when being ran in HTML:

```
2014-04-07T19:48:00
```

I'm trying to get it to be as:

```
April 7 19:48 (no years).
```

How would I do it? this.find.text() makes it difficult to figure out. substr() has worked for taking the year out but I need the month converted to a string such as 04 to April.

This is for random dates being generated from parsed XML. Not just one day.

Comment: AJAX was used to call a C# page that calls the XML service. Not really related. Edited.

Comment: Are you looking for a jQuery solution or just javascript?

Comment: Either would be appreciated!

Comment: Also welcome to StackOverflow :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to basically build an array with your Months. You would then use the `Date` object property `.getMonth()` which will then output a number which is when you'll need your array:

```
function formatDate (dateFromXmlDoc) {    
var theDate = new Date(dateFromXmlDoc);
var theMonth = theDate.getMonth(); //returns 3


var monthArray = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "November", "December"];
return monthArray[theMonth]; //Outputs 'April'
}
```

After this, you can then build your date format into what you wish

Comment: what if you are dealing with thousand of different dates coming from XML? This is for static. Wasn't very clear sorry

Comment: Then you pass the date string to the date object. I just used the static date you provided. In reality you will replace this with the variable

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Date object in javascript:

`var x = new Date("2014-04-07T19:48:00");`

and call all the functions on this page on that object:

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp

Comment: mwilson's answer is also relevant in that the Date object will not return a month's actual name, only it's index

Answer (score 0):

```
function convertDate(date) {
  // array with month names
  months = [
    "January", "February", "March",
    "April", "May", "June",
    "July", "August", "September",
    "October", "November", "December"
  ];

  // Since date is in ISO 8601 format, we can count on
  // positions of parts of the date within the string;
  // if this were not true, we'd rather use the less
  // efficient but more robust 'split' method to get
  // the date parts.
  // Also, we must convert zero-prefixed strings to
  // integers, and look-up the month string in the array.
  // One might be tempted to use the "new Date(date)" to
  // get a date object, but it is too smart for our purposes,
  // as it takes the time-zone into account.
  return months[parseInt(date.substr(5, 2))-1] + " " 
        + parseInt(date.substr(8, 2)) + " "
        + date.substr(11, 5);
}

convertDate("2014-11-12T04:48:00");
```